# Go JSON with simplejson

Tags: json, go

Trying to use the JSON lib from "github.com/bitly/go-simplejson"

```
url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=1"
res, err := http.Get(url)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(body)) //WORKS
js, err := simplejson.NewJson(body)

total,_ := js.Get("total").String()    
fmt.Printf("Total:%s"+total )
```

But it seems it doenst work !?
Trying to access the total and tag fields

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: I get a "MISSING" when i print the variable "total"

Comment: Well, it maybe just a typo — you are trying to get field `totla` instead `total` you mentioned.

Comment: Nahh *fixed* the typo but still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few mistakes:

1. If you'll check the JSON response you'll notice that `total` field is not string, that's why you should use `MustInt()` method, not `String()`, when you are accessing the field.
2. `Printf()` method invocation was totally wrong. You should pass a "template", and then pass arguments appropriate to the number of "placeholders".

By the way, I strongly recomend you to check `err != nil` everywhere, that'll help you a lot.

Here is the working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/bitly/go-simplejson"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=1"
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(body))

    js, err := simplejson.NewJson(body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    total := js.Get("total").MustInt()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Total:%s", total)
}
```

Comment: The error check after the `total` assignment doesn't seem to be checking anything, since MustInt() isn't affecting the state of `err`.